# How to create a static member in clojure

Tags: clojure, static

I have a class(created by deftype) and I want to make several static members like deserialize on it. I tried to add theirs signatures in interface but it is'nt worked for me(code below).

```
(definterface INmk
  (serialize [])
  (deserialize [string])
  (print []))

(deftype NmkLinear [^:volatile-mutable a
                    ^:volatile-mutable b
                    ^:volatile-mutable x-sum
                    ^:volatile-mutable y-sum
                    ^:volatile-mutable xy-sum
                    ^:volatile-mutable xq-sum
                    ^:volatile-mutable n]  
  INmk
  (serialize [this]
    (str "{\"a\":" a
         " \"b\":" b
         " \"x-sum\":" x-sum
         " \"y-sum\":" y-sum
         " \"xy-sum\":" xy-sum
         " \"xq-sum\":" xq-sum
         " \"n\":" n
         "}"))

  (deserialize [str]
    (let [j (json/read-str str :key-fn keyword)]
      (NmkLinear.
       (:a j) (:b j) (:x-sum j) (:y-sum j) (:xy-sum j) (:xq-sum j) (:n j))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interfaces in Java don't allow static methods to be defined on them; the only static members allowed are constants (where any field you create is assumed to be static and final), the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/interfaces.html) says, "The access modifier static pertains only to member interfaces". If Java can't do this then Clojure's `definterface` can't either, of course.

Static methods are not polymorphic so defining them on an interface would not be useful anyway. Keep things like deserialize as stand-alone functions instead (or otherwise look for a different way to organize this).

EDIT: Starting with Java 8 you can add static methods to an interface, so most of the above is out-of-date. (Also I'm not clear whether Clojure is on supporting this.)  It seems from your example this is not actually what you want, though. If you add it to the interface then the method implementation will be the same for all implementations of the interface.

Comment: **Note:** that Java8 **does** allow static method bodies to be defined on interfaces [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.4.3) and example -  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html

Comment: @Scott: >_< just when i think i know something. thanks, i'll check this out.

Comment: Clojure 1.6.0 does not support the Java 8 changes around methods on interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

If you genuinely need a static method for some reason, then you need to fall back to gen-class.

http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/gen-class

This lets you annotate methods with the appropriate metadata to specify they should be static.

```
^{:static true}
```

As Nathan says, static members don't apply to interfaces.